# How do I create a button like the snapshot in Kivy or KivyMD?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

Attached is an image from Magento Admin page. I want to create a button-system like this in (Kivy or KivyMD) and Python - a large icon with text below. I tried hard to look for samples, or use the Kitchen Sink demo, couldn't find anything near it, and I don't know the keywords to search for. Would I need to create a custom button, or is there already something in Kivy or KivyMD? If there is, what is it called?

And additional related question - Is it beneficial to use a font (like fontawesome) as the icon, or using a PNG image will be okay?

[Snapshot from Magento Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3kNf.png)

Comment: You can create your own class that extends some `Layout` and Button Behavior. It could contain an `Image` and a `Label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import kivy.core.clipboard
import requests 



import os
if os.path.exists("_python_bundle/")==False:
    try:
        Window.size=(350,600)
    except:
        pass

kv = '''
#:import MDTextField kivymd.uix.textfield.MDTextField
#:import Clipboard kivy.core.clipboard.Clipboard

Screen:
    name: "jbsidis"
    MDBottomNavigationBar:
        id: jbsidis_bar_23
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: [0,0,0,.4]
            Line:
                width: dp(0.5)
                rectangle:
                    (self.x, self.height, self.width, dp(1))
        size_hint: .2,1
        height: dp(10) #56
        elevation: 0
        md_bg_color: [0.1,0,0.1,1] #[1,1,1,1]
 


        FloatLayout:
            MDIconButton:
                id: b1_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .96}
                markup: True
                icon: "cube-scan"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,0,0,.9]
                on_release: print(12, "jbsidis")
            MDSeparator:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .93}
                color: [1,1,1,.5]
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: .7
                height: "1dp"
                
            MDIconButton:
                id: b2_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .9}
                markup: True
                icon: "speedometer"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release: print(12, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .87}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]DASHBOARD" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
        
                
            MDIconButton:
                id: b3_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .82}
                markup: True
                icon: "currency-usd"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release:
                    print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .79}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]SALES" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
        
                
            MDIconButton:
                id: b4_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .74}
                markup: True
                icon: "cube-outline"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release: print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .71}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]CATALOG" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
        
                
            MDIconButton:
                id: b5_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .66}
                markup: True
                icon: "clipboard-account"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release: print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .62}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]CUSTOMER" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
        
                
            MDIconButton:
                id: b6_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .57}
                markup: True
                icon: "speaker-wireless"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release: print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .53}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]MARKETING" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
           #
            MDIconButton:
                id: b7_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .48}
                markup: True
                icon: "solar-panel"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release: print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .45}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]CONTENT" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
           
            MDIconButton:
                id: b7_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .38}
                markup: True
                icon: "chart-bar"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release: print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .35}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]REPORTS" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
           
            MDIconButton:
                id: b7_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .30}
                markup: True
                icon: "store-outline"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release: print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .28}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]STORES" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
           
            MDIconButton:
                id: b7_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .21}
                markup: True
                icon: "file-settings-variant-outline"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release: print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .17}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=9]SYSTEM" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]
           
            MDSeparator:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .14}
                color: [1,1,1,.5]
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: .7
                height: "1dp"
                
            MDIconButton:
                id: b7_jbsidis
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .11}
                markup: True
                icon: "puzzle"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: [1,1,1,.9]
                on_release:
                    print(23, "jbsidis")
            MDTextButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .07}
                markup: True
                font_style: "Caption"
                text: "[color=ffffff][b][size=8]FIND PARTNERS\\n&  EXTENSIONS" #for pc size is 6, for cellphone [size=15]


'''
x = "jbsidis: kivy or kivymd, python can do everything java kotlin react etc can, Python and Kivy are amazing"
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

class JBSIDIS(OneLineIconListItem):
    pass
class blanks1(BoxLayout):
    pass
class S(FloatLayout):
    pass


Web_links = "jbsidis"
books = """
jbsidis
"""
class Main_jbsidis(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        global app
        global jbsidis
        jbsidis="jbsidis"
        app=MDApp.get_running_app()
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


Main_jbsidis().run()
```

Pictures:

[image]

Comment: In case you get an error "No module named requests" just comment the line "import requests" out, that line is not required for this example unless you need to connect to the internet using requests module

Comment: Very useful! I will study your code to understand the details.

Comment: Using python and kivy for your programs and apps will help you to achieve your goal super fast, it has the same potential as any other programming language but you will save a lot of time in developing, the FloatLayout class is key sometimes, but also there are some class that comes with kivymd framework that you can use, check my profile to view more code examples for kivy and python